# Use dynamic programming to find a polygonal chain that best fits a set of data points

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The question is stated as the following:

Given a sequence of n points p_1= (x_1,y_1),...,p_n=(x_n,y_n) and sorted from left to right by it x-coordinate (i.e. x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n) and a number k between 1 and n. We want to **find a polygonal chain from p1 to pn with k edges that goes from left to right, minimizing the sum of the vertical distances of the points to the chain**. Design a dynamic programming algorithm to solve the problem in O(n^3) time. The method to calculate the sum of the vertical distances of the points p_a+1, . . . , p_b-1 to the line through
p_ap_b. is given by f(a,b).

[image]

Since it is difficult for me to write an example to test, so I don't know whether my answer is corrent or not.

The answer is as the following:

Firstly, I define C[i,j] = polygonal chain end at pi with j edges, the minimum sum of vertical distances. And the answer should be C[n,k].

For the base case, I define C[i,0] = 0 and C[i,j] = +infinity when j>=i.

For the recursive formula, I define C[i,j] = minimum (1 < p < i) { C[p , j-1] + f(p,i) }

Are there anything wrong with my answer? Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to define the function *f*

Comment: Also I don't see a real question here. Do you just want to verify that your recurrence is correct?

Comment: I am sorry for no function definition since I can't upload image. Yes, do my recurrence is correct for the problem that:
We want to find a polygonal chain from p1 to pn with k edges that goes from left to right, minimizing the sum of the vertical distances of the points to the chain.

Comment: Then at least post the link in the question or a comment so that we can edit it in for you

Comment: It is available now, I am sorry for that.

Comment: In that case, I believe your recurrence is correct.

Comment: On of your base cases are wrong I'm afraid.  C[1, 0] = 0, but C[i, 0] should be +inf for i > 1, since you can't even get to such a point p_i with 0 edges if your path must start at p_1.

Comment: Separately, there's the question of whether or not the internal vertices of the path need to lie exactly on points p_i or not.  As stated, only the first and last points need to lie on p_1 and p_n, respectively, and it might be that a lower total weight could be achieved by putting internal path vertices at different (e.g. fractional-coordinate) positions.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Do you have a counterexample? My intuition is that there is always an optimal solution where the polyline vertices are points from the chain, but I'm not sure

Comment: @NiklasB. With one segment and a chain like |x| for x in [-1,1], you want the segment at y=0.5, which connects two vertices but not the end ones.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Certainly there's an O(n log n) algorithm for one segment, by the crude technique of binary search on the slope and taking medians. Perhaps it can be done in O(n).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat But y=1 is a better solution than y=0.5 if I'm interpreting the cost function corrrectly (cost 1 for y=1 vs. 1.5 for y=0.5). EDIT oh you mean with granularity of x going towards infinity?

Comment: @NiklasB. Oops, yes, "infinite" granularity.

Comment: @NiklasB.: No counterexample yet.  Certainly the fact that the penalty function is |error| rather than error^2 backs up your intuition.  I can at least say that if you have a line segment whose x positions come from the set of points (say from x_i to x_j), and you move one of the endpoints of this line segment up or down, but not so much that any data point crosses the line, then the cost function (for this particular line segment) will behave linearly, so it will always be minimised by moving this endpoint up or down until the first time it touches a data point p_m with i <= m <= j.

Answer (score 1):

Example where it is better to use point not in `P` (set of `p_i`) for a chain.

```
P = {(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 1), (4, 0)}
k = 2

        + (2,2)

    * (1,1) * (3,1)

* (0,0)        * (4,0)
```

There are 2 possibilities for a chain with points in `P`, both have `f(1,4) = 2/3`. Taking `(2, 2)` as chain point gives `f(1,4) = 0`.

Solution of problem without restriction that chain points are in `P`, is probably hard to describe in DP manner. It looks more like regression problem with a lot of constraints.

I suppose that in this problem it is expected for a chain points to be from `P`.

**Update**

Lower recursion is same as original, like j_random_hacker mentioned.

I think that it is better to define slightly different function. Define `C(a, b, e)` as minimal cost of chain between points `p_a` and `p_b` with `e` edges. Answer to our problem is `C(1, n, k)`.

```
C(a, b, 1) = f(a,b)
C(a, a+i, i) = 0
C(a, b, k) = inf, k > b-a
```

There are different recursions that can be used. This one is by 'length' of last edge:

```
C(a, b, k+1) = min( C(a, c, k) + C(i, b, 1) ), for i in a+k, b-1
```

Comment: +1 for your counterexample :)  I don't think your recursion helps, though -- I think it computes the same thing as the original recursion, but slower because it uses 1 more parameter.

Comment: @j_random_hacker You are right, this is exactly the same recursion as original one. Only 2 types of C() appear: C(1, i, k) (in original C[i,k]) and C(i, b, 1) (f(i,b)). Definition of C(a,b,e) offers different types of recursion: from beginning (like original), from end (opposite), ... Which isn't of too much help at the end :-/